# Django - AttributeError: module 'environ' has no attribute 'ENV'

Tags: python, django, environment-variables

Installed Python 3.9 on Windows 10. Also installed Django 3.2 Django-environ 0.8. But I don't know why this raise an error when I tried to run

```
python manage.py runserver
```

My code:

```
import environ
from pathlib import Path
env = environ.ENV(DEBUG=(bool, False))
```

The error:

```
AttributeError: module 'environ' has no attribute 'ENV'
```

Comment: The error means there is no `ENV` symbol defined in environ module. Please verify your package version and implementation from the readme

Comment: did you [ pip install django-environ ] ?

Comment: Share complete error trace

Comment: Check `django-environ` is installed in your machine or not using `pip freeze | grep 'django'`

Comment: I use dotenv module instead, and it seems to work

Answer (score 0):

You need to change ENV to Env.

env = environ.**ENV**(DEBUG=(bool, False))

env = environ.**Env**(DEBUG=(bool, False))

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it is by;

```
 from environ import Env
 from pathlib import Path
 env = Env(DEBUG=(bool, False))
```

Make sure sure you have also added django_environ via pip

```
pip install django-environ
```

If you are using requirements.txt file make sure that it is updated